# PyCharm won't import PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I'm fairly new to python and decided to try PyGame only to find it won't import.

```
line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I am on windows 10, I am using PyCharm Build #PE-182.3684.126, and I pip installed it through CMD. I have reinstalled PyGame twice so far and it still won't work. If anyone can provide advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your PyCharm project running in a virtual environment? And if it is, did you install pygame to that environment? (Did you use cmd or the terminal in PyCharm to install pygame?)

Comment: I used cmd to install pygame

Comment: Have you restarted PyCharm since your `pip install`? You might need to.

Comment: I just tried it then and no, it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried running your script from cmd? Also what is the output of `where pip` and `where python`?

Comment: running through cmd does not workwhere pip gives                                                                                %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe where python gives                                      %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

Comment: Can you import pygame in python shell?

Comment: Open a python shell in cmd and try to import pygame. If that works the problem could be the environment PyCharm is using is different to the environment you installed pygame.  

When you open the code in PyCharm, does `import pygame` have a red line under it? If it does, hover over it, click the light bulb and choose `install package`. That will install the package to the environment pycharm is using

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael, cmd gave back `Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html`
                                                                                                             and no it doesn't have a red line under it in PyCharm infact it has a green tick on the right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your PyCharm project. Go to `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`. There will be a list of all installed modules on the current python environment you are using. If *pygame* is not listed there, it hasn't been installed for that PyCharm project (using that python environment).

[image: Pygame environment]

You can install it by using PyCharm interface, just click on the **+** sign and search for pygame and click install.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve the problem. I had the same problem as well and the reason is I think you need to **specify version** and fill in the **option** before you click the install button in Pycharm. For example my version is 1.9.6 and the option is I fill in the sentences below the Author which is "A community project". This is basically how i solve my problem try to get pygame install in my pycharm. I hope you are having the same problem too.

So go to :
File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter

Click the plus button '+' on the top right window
Search for pygame
and fill in the version and option
Install Package
It works for me at last!

Answer (score 0):

In A Short way You can Do it Open Terminal Of Pycham (you can see below downside)And Try The `pip Install pygame`
Its work fine for my laptop and conputer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install pygame` at the terminal in pycharm, or simply click on *Python Packages* and search for pygame (to install it).

[image]

[image]