# Getting Import error while importing face_recognition in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, face-recognition

I am new to PyCharm and trying some face recognition stuff. I need a face_recogniton library for my work which is installed using the following command (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 as my OS):

```
pip install face_recognition
```

I am able to import it in python interpreter but it throws import error in PyCharm

`ImportError: No module named 'face_recognition'`.

Thanks for your effort in helping me.

Comment: check you interpreter in pycharm. if its python3.5 then use `pip3 install face_recognition`

Comment: Did you configure your PyCharm project to use the same Python interpreter as `pip` uses? Compare `pip --version` with `PyCharm > Preferences > Project Interpreter`.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I get the following path for pip: pip 18.1 from /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5) how should I configure in Pycharm now?

Comment: Open pycharm goto file then settings then interpreter then installed libraries then search for your library and install it.

Answer (score 1):

For installing face-recognition module for Ubuntu 18.04: (Try for other OS, I used this for 18.04)

1. Install cmake: `pip install cmake`
   After cmake is successfully installed
2. Optional: Install git if you don't have git

   git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
3. build the main dlib library

   cd dlib
   mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; cmake --build .
4. Build and install python essentials

   cd ..
   python3 setup.py install

After all this run these to verify

```
python3 
>> import dlib
```

5. Now install face_recognition

   pip3 install face_recognition

Takes some time but that is okay! I hope it worked for you

Refer these materials:

1. face-recognition original repo: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installing-on-mac-or-linux
2. dlib: https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf

Answer (score 0):

Reading [face_recognition installation guide on github](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installing-on-mac-or-linux), make sure you have dlib installed and then install face_recognition with:

> pip3 install face_recognition

Also, check if PyCharm is using environment where you installed face_recognition. Maybe PyCharm created it's own virtual env and you are using it without face_recognition.

For more info about how to install module in PyCharm env, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53580808/9871463), just except pygame check if face_recognition is listed. If not, install it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have installed maybe multiple versions of Python. You seem to have installed face_recognition for python version 2, whereas you are trying to access the module from Python version 3. You should consider using virtual environments and set up Python Interpreter accordingly.

Follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html on how to configure the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Download this file `cmake-3.17.0-rc3-win64-x64.msi` from [cmake.org](https://cmake.org/download/) and install it (By default it will be installed in `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`).

After the installation copy this path and edit environment variable -> path -> paste that path -> click ok. Open the cmd and now use `pip install face_recognition`

i hope it should work....