# Pygame window does not show up at all. It doesn't even say any error, it just says "pygame 1.9.6 Hello from the pygame community."

Tags: macos, pygame, pycharm

I put in this code......

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
myfont = pygame.font.Sysfont("Arial", 60)
label = myfont.render("Hello Ahat", 1, (255, 255, 0))

window.blit(label, (100, 100,))
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(5)

pygame.quit()
```

Pygame window does not show up at all. It doesn't even say error, it just says "pygame 2.0.0 dev6 Hello from the pygame community."

Comment: The question has the `pycharm` tag.  Do you also get this issue running outside of PyCharm?  Maybe you could try a simple program of `import pygame` and `print( pygame.version.ver )`.  Your code has a few bugs/typos, so it should at least generate an error.  I suspect a problem with PyCharm.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you can you explain it once again? Ive never tried running that code outside of Pycharm, because this is the only thing I use, or ever used

Comment: Try this workthrough: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010202240  or this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575888/pycharm-wont-import-pygame

Comment: It does do the same when I run the code in terminal. Just says "Pygame 2.0.0dev6, Hello from the pygame community"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not address when to close the window, and the program was closing it right away. So this is what I eventually wrote:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```